# Returning data from images in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I'm quite rusty with my (basic) javascript so hopefully I'm not misunderstanding the problem entirely, but essentially what I'm trying to do is return the 'alt' field of an image as a caption appended to the title for each image, and while I'm getting essentially that, it's returning the list for the entire sequence of images to each instead of their own in a sequence. Code is super simple, which is probably why it's not working. Any help is appreciated

```
$('#projectThumbs img').each(function(){
  $('.project-title').append("<div>" + $(this).attr('alt') + "</div>");
    });
```

For example, if the images have a caption sequence of '1','2','3', each image is now being appended with '1,2,3' instead of '1' to 1, '2' to 2, etc.

Images structure from the html (in Squarespace so I don't have access to source code, only injection). This is in a grid of images.

ETA: noticed a few hiding divs in the code, maybe the project-item-count can be useful in some way?

```
<a class='project'>
    <div>
        <div class='project-image'>
            <div class='intrinsic'>
              <div class = 'content-fill'>
                 <img alt='example'>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class='project-item-count'>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='project-title'>
            Title
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

[image of what's happening to help clarify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHlHa.jpg)

Comment: Please share your HTML code as well. `.project-title` selects all the elements with this class, but you probably wanted to scope-in the inner elements.

Comment: This is through squarespace, but the images are all standard <img alt='example'> and I'm just trying to pull the alt text

Comment: this looks like it should work, assume the selectors (`#projectThumbs img` and `.project-title`) match elements in your HTML. (And that the images actually have `alt` attributes.) We need more detail if it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the html. That looks ok to me, the only thing I can think of is to check that you're putting your jQuery code inside a `$(document).ready` handler. Otherwise it might try to run before the image elements are in the DOM, in which case it will have no effect,

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'm not sure that's the issue. It seems to be running fine, but still returning too many values instead of the relevant value for each instance (see screengrab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.project-image img').each(function(){
  $(this).parents('.project-image').next().append("<div>" + $(this).attr('alt') + "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='project'>
    <div>
        <div class='project-image'>
            <div class='intrinsic'>
              <div class = 'content-fill'>
                 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt='example1'>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class='project-item-count'>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='project-title'>
            Title
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<a class='project'>
    <div>
        <div class='project-image'>
            <div class='intrinsic'>
              <div class = 'content-fill'>
                 <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt='example2'>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class='project-item-count'>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='project-title'>
            Title
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This seems to just break the captions, I don't think it likes having to go through parent divs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML contains valid `#projectThumbs` element, the problem is that you're not targeting the `.project-title` element(s) correctly.

You need to do that using `parent()` (to find the parent of the element), and then use `siblings()` to find the correct sibling (which has `project-title` class assigned).

See the demo below:

```js
$('#projectThumbs img').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings('.project-title').append("<div>" + $(this).attr('alt') + "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="projectThumbs">
  <a class='project'>
    <div>
      <div class='project-image'>
        <img alt='example'>
      </div>
      <div class='project-title'>
        Title
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to fix anything, just made the captions disappear entirely

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute cannot be duplicated in DOM elements so each function is not run on all the same id elements if you use the class attribute with the same name and use each function then your problem solved.i hope it helps you.

```js
$('#projectThumbs img').each(function(){
  $('.project-title').append("<p>" + $(this).attr('alt') + "</p>");
    });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <div id="projectThumbs">
    <img alt="myimae" 
src="http://psdandcode.com/themes/psd2code/images/logo.png">
    <img alt="mimage" 
 src="http://psdandcode.com/themes/psd2code/images/logo.png">
    <img alt="myimae" 
  src="http://psdandcode.com/themes/psd2code/images/logo.png">
    <img alt="myimag" 
 src="http://psdandcode.com/themes/psd2code/images/logo.png">

</div>
<div class="project-title"></div>
```

Comment: if you have any confusion you can ask. I will change the code according to your requirement.